# Python requests not looking into /etc/ssl/certs for self-signed certificates

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, ssl-certificate, certifi

I'm trying to add a certificate into a Dockerfile, needed for Python requests package:

```sh
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/app"
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app .
COPY ./certs/*.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN pip3 install requests
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

With the above Dockerfile, I get the following error:

```sh
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Based on my tests, that is because `requests` is using `certifi` and is looking only inside `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`. If I add my certificates inside `cacert.pem`, everything works as expected and the errors are gone.

What is the pythonic way to deal with this issue? Ideally, I would prefer to insert certificates into a directory, instead of modifying a file. Is there a way to "force" Python `requests` look inside `/etc/ssl/certs` for certificates, as well into certifi `cacert.pem` file? If I list the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory contents, it contains my .pem certificates.

Running an `apt-get update` will not update `ca-certificates`, I'm already using the latest version. When I execute `update-ca-certificates`, the new certificates are detected:

```sh
STEP 10/11: RUN update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
2 added, 0 removed; done.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There only reasonable solution I found is:

```py
from requests import post
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError, RequestException, SSLError

try:
    result = post(url=url, data=dumps(data), headers=headers, verify='/etc/ssl/certs')
except (HTTPError, RequestException, SSLError) as e:
    raise
```

Setting `verify=/etc/ssl/certs` will see the self-signed certificates.